# 403 Forbidden, when uploading site to drupal

Tags: php, .htaccess, azure, drupal, drupal-7

I have Virtual Machine hosted on Azure with Drupal.

In `drupal/htdocs/sites` i have created new folder with name `my-site.com`

Then I have uploaded all my website data to this folder. They are `default.settings.php`, `settings.php` and `files` folder.

I have uploaded my database via phpMyAdmin and set proper login and password in `settings.php`

When I try to open this site via this url: `http://my.ip.address/sites/my-site.com` it shows me an error message:

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /sites/my-site.com/ on this server.
```

My htaccess file has these following lines:

```
# Turn off all options we don't need.
Options None
Options +FollowSymLinks

# Set the catch-all handler to prevent scripts from being executed.
SetHandler Drupal_Security_Do_Not_Remove_See_SA_2006_006
<Files *>
# Override the handler again if we're run later in the evaluation list.
SetHandler Drupal_Security_Do_Not_Remove_See_SA_2013_003
</Files>

# If we know how to do it safely, disable the PHP engine entirely.
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
  php_flag engine off
</IfModule>
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

According the post http://planken.org/2013/11/drupal-724-htaccess-modifications-private-and-temp-folders, it seems that the content in your `.htaccess` file is to protect the code and files and to prevent code execution in the directory.

To run the complete Drupal application in the sub-directory, you can try to copy the original `.htaccess` file in the root directory to the sub-directory.

You can get the sample `.htaccess` file at https://github.com/drupal/drupal/blob/8.1.x/.htaccess

Answer (score 0):

You should first check that there is a .htaccess file in the docroot of your site.  Sometimes when you copy a site over hidden files in the docroot are omitted.  The following command will copy the missing hidden files:

```
cp source/.* destination/
```

The .htaccess you posted is in your files directory which isn't the main .htaccess we care about for trying to access the site via index.php